# Using django-oscar to sell fully custom products

Tags: django-oscar

I am looking into using `django-oscar` to sell custom-made products. There is only one SKU, but it has 4 properties that customers can specify: chemicals, color, scent and weight.

- Chemicals is a JSON object (a dictionary of name/value pairs), and we will need to use that to keep track of inventory of the chemicals.
- Weight is an integer between 200 and 20000.
- Scent and color each have a dozen values at present.

Customers will make up recipes and share them with each other. A recipe is a combination of the 4 properties.

Product will be made to order, so we will only stock raw ingredients, not finished product.

We already have an HTML/JavaScript page that allows customers to choose values for the 4 product properties. Costing needs to be done via an Ajax call to an API that needs to be exposed by Django.

Currently, there is one fulfillment partner (me), but out of the box `django-oscar` only applies fulfillment partners to fully defined products.

It seems (but I am a bit uncertain) that `manage.py oscar_fork_app` creates forked Oscar apps within an existing webapp, like Frobshop... is that right?

It seems from what I read that `django-oscar` is capable of selling custom products such as I describe. I think that I'll need to fork the Catalogue and the Dashboard apps. Will I also need to fork Basket and Order and Partner also?

How would I approach setting this type of store up? I have looked at https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/customisation.html, but I have not tried to move forward yet, still trying to get a handle on things.

I decided to try and see what happened. I decided to call the root module `ancientwarmth`. The following worked just fine, and I forked `catalogue`, `dashboard`, `basket`, `order` and `partner`.

```sh
for x in catalogue dashboard basket order partner; do
  ./manage.py oscar_fork_app $x ancientwarmth
  sed -i s/oscar.apps.$x.apps.${x^}/ancientwarmth.$x.apps.${x^}/ \
    frobshop/settings/base.py
done
```

However, I was unable to fork any of these:

- `oscar.apps.dashboard.orders.apps.OrdersDashboardConfig`
- `oscar.apps.dashboard.catalogue.apps.CatalogueDashboardConfig`
- `oscar.apps.dashboard.partners.apps.PartnersDashboardConfig`

I got an error like `CommandError: There is no app with the label 'dashboard.catalogue'`.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a broad question, and not one that is likely to get a comprehensive answer because of the time it would take to write one, but a few comments (and help with the forking error):

1. It's quite possible to sell custom products using Oscar.
2. Which apps you need to fork really depends on your use case and what from Oscar's core functionality you need to override. You need to first develop a good understanding of what Oscar's apps provide out of the box to determine whether you need to override their functionality. It's not really possible to answer in the general case what apps you need to fork. Oscar is designed to give you as much flexibility to override its functionality as possible - knowing when/where to do this does require becoming familiar with its functionality first though.
3. The first argument to `oscar_fork_app` is the [label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.label) of a Django `AppConfig`, not a module name, which is what you're trying to use. That is why you're getting an error when attempting to fork the dashboard apps. The correct command would be `manage.py oscar_fork_app catalogue_dashboard <destination_path>`. This isn't made very clear in the documentation, and there is an [issue to fix this](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/3486). `catalogue_dashboard` is [defined here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/dashboard/catalogue/apps.py#L9).

   (It worked for the `catalogue`, `basket`, etc. apps because for those the app name defined for the app is identical to the argument you supplied).

Comment: I'm now reading the Oscar source code so I can obtain "a good understanding of what Oscar's apps provide out of the box" because the docs I found do not say much that is useful or insightful. Can you recommend a faster way to learn?

Comment: As shown above, I used oscar_fork_app without an error message for apps catalogue, dashboard, basket, order and partner. Was that incorrect?

Comment: To your first comment - the most effective way to learn in my view is to look at Oscar's source code. To the second comment, forking of those apps worked because the argument you supplied is identical to the app name. `dashboard.catalogue`, however, isn't, which is why forking of the dashboard sub-apps failed.

Comment: I would be interested in any feedback on this: https://www.mslinn.com/blog/2021/02/24/django-oscar-app-like.html